# Аннотации python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Захотел повысить читабельность кода и решил использовать в проекте аннотации:

```
def delete_city(id_user: int, number_city: int) -> Union[str, Literal['Error_delete']]:
```

Но в итоге получаю это:

[image: код]

Literal просто не отображается в аннотации. Как это исправить, чтобы получилось str | Literal['Error_delete']

По умолчанию python пишет так:

[image: код2]

Comment: Такая аннотация не имеет смысла, потому что `'Error_delete'` это и есть `str`. И обозначать ошибку строкой это в принципе плохая идея

Comment: Как тогда будет правильно обозначить ошибку?

Comment: @KillmeNull Хороший способ при ошибке кидать исключение, например. Кстати, а что ваша функция возвращает в случае успеха? По идее функция удаления не должна ничего возвращать в случае успеха, поэтому можно было бы сделать её типа `bool` и возвращать статус - успешно удаление прошло или нет (`True` или `False`). Но если нужно таки и правда что-то возвращать, то можно сделать класс с двумя полями - результатом и статусом ошибки, например. В общем, вариантов море. Но самый типовой это всё-таки кидать исключение в случае ошибки.

Comment: В общем, в идеале ошибка должна быть типизированной - либо это какое-то исключение, унаследованное от `Exception`, либо специальный ваш класс с ошибкой.